# How can I append only 1 value for iteration?

Tags: python

I need to only append the first value of every iteration that I do. I need to divide every value in 2 parts and appending to my list the letters that are in common between 2 parts. Sometimes I have 2 letters in common between the 2 parts but I want to append only the first one. How can I do this?

```
list = []
for riga in file:
    rucksack = riga.strip()
    if rucksack:
        first = rucksack[:len(rucksack)//2]
        second = rucksack[len(rucksack)//2:]
        for item in first:
            if item in second:       
                list.append(item)
                print(list)
```

I tried this but sometimes It appends 2 letters instead 1. The problem is located in the following syntax.

```
    for item in first:
        if item in second:       
            list.append(item)
            print(list)
```

I want to append only the 1st value of every iteration.

Comment: To find the common letters you could put both your partial rucksacks in a `set` and calculate the intersection of both. Happy advent.

Comment: This question would be improved with the addition of  example input and expected output vs. actual output for your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `break`:

```
//...
list.append(item)
print(list)
break  # Stop the loop once the first common letter is found
```

By the way, I'd suggest using a different name for your list :)

Comment: thank you so much <3 yeah you suggest that because it's better not using a function name right?